# Angular 4 - Firefox: NgOnInit() isn't called after constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, webpack

After a redirection (router.navigate), one of my components is created, but its ngOnInit() function is never called.
It's working fine with Chrome, this bug only appears with Firefox.
I've tried putting a console.log in the constructor and it prints - however, I'm not certain that the construction process actually finishes (no way to log that, and the step by step debug is illegible).

The resolvers gathering data do work, and the requests to my APIs are successful.

Using Angular 4.3.1 with webpack 3.12.0 and Firefox 63.0.3.

If you have any idea where I could look, it would help a lot.

home.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedModule } from '../../app/shared/shared.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './components';
import { MessageHomeResolver } from './resolvers';

const childRoutesHome: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        resolve: { 
            messages: MessageHomeResolver, 
        }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        RouterModule.forChild(childRoutesHome), 
        SharedModule 
    ],
    declarations:  [HomeComponent],
    exports: [HomeComponent],
    providers: [ ]
})

export class HomeModule {}
```

home.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '../../../../node_modules/@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '../../../../node_modules/@angular/router';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './home.component.scss' ],
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }
    
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('working');
        // This console.log() doesn't show
    };
```

Comment: Is that complete code of HomeComponent  constructor?

Comment: It's a strange behaivor, check if there're an error in your code. By the way, use import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core' (not from .../.../.../node_modules/@angular/core)

Comment: @Ritesh Yes, in the actual code there's more but this is a simplified code which presents the same problem (tested and same behaviour).

Comment: @Eliseo I know, I usually do this too, it doesn't change the behaviour of the program.